# MongoDB For Loop updates wrong user

Tags: javascript, mongodb, for-loop, mongoose, twitch

So I've been programming a Twitch chat bot in Javascript, and am using a MongoDB to store information about a user. There is a mini-game where after a few "attacks" the monster can be defeated, and users will be awarded with the XP from the battle. There is an array of users in the current battle to be awarded, as well as a list of users that were defeated. They still get XP, but their "Wins" aren't updated. The problem is that I'm doing this using a for loop, until it has updated every user in the array. This works, but is extremely buggy, which I assume is because the function is looping before the database has chance to catch up (not sure if this is the case, but it's my assumption). Basically when the database is trying to update the user, it will sometimes update the same person multiple times, and not update other people.

Any ideas what's causing it, and if my assumption sounds right, how I can avoid this?

```
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: [ARENA] The boss was defeated by 'madmikegamerxl1'. The boss health is: -30
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: ethelwolv
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 0/8(ethelwolv)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: shauncox12345
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 1/8(shauncox12345)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: orpheussummanus
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 2/8(orpheussummanus)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: acermekz21
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 3/8(acermekz21)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: sturgisdanielle
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 4/8(sturgisdanielle)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: minnie2292
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 5/8(minnie2292)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: epicminer4354
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 6/8(epicminer4354)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: madmikegamerxl1
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:25 GMT] INFO: Finished updating user 7/8(madmikegamerxl1)
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:26 GMT] INFO: User 'x0slipknot0x' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
[Tue, 05 Apr 2016 21:45:28 GMT] INFO: User 'madmikegamerxl1' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count
```

So as you can see it is only updating some people. I'll post the For loop code, as well as one of the functions that updates the stats (I know my code is not efficient at all, and is probably unnecessarily long, but I'm just making sure it functions for now) :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arenaConfig.users.length; i++) { // Game was won! Adding XP to every user instead of 1 user.
     var currentUserI = arenaConfig.users[i];

     globalLog("info", "Game was won, looping to add XP and restore users. Current user: " + currentUserI, channel);

     searchUser(currentUserI, channel.substr(1), function (dataReturned) {

         if (dataReturned == "new" || dataReturned == "err") { }
         else {
             updateUserHealthdb(db, currentUserI, dataReturned.stats.health, function () {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 // Restored health to user.
                 updateXP(xpToAdd, currentUserI, function () {
                     if (arenaConfig.deadUsers.indexOf(currentUserI) >= 0) { // User was defeated
                         globalLog("info", "User was defeated by the boss, skipping updateWin function. - " + currentUserI, channel);

                     }
                     else {
                         globalLog("info", "User '" + currentUserI + "' was not defeated by the boss, incrementing win count", channel);
                         setTimeout(function () {
                             updateWin(1, currentUserI, function () {
                             });

                         }, 1000);
                     }
                 });
                 globalLog("success", "Successfully restored user's health to: " + dataReturned.stats.health, channel);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

 });


 globalLog("info", "Finished updating user " + i + "/" + arenaConfig.users.length + "(" + currentUserI + ")", channel);


 }
```

And below is the function that updates the statistics in the database (all of the update functions have similar code, just tweaked for the different DB fields)

```
function updateXP(num, user, callback) {

    dbuser.findOne({ 'name': user }, 'name stats.xp', function (err, person) {
        if (person != null) {
            person.stats.xp = person.stats.xp + num;
            person.save();
            globalLog("info", 'update: ' + person.name + ' [' + person.stats.xp + ' ' + "XP" + ' ]');
            callback();
        }
    });

};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Does your code ever enter this block?  If there is an error, your code fails silently.

```
if (dataReturned == "new" || dataReturned == "err") { }
```

Also, do you have a single MongoDB server or a cluster?  If it is clustered, a read is "eventually consistent".  So if you write a user to the master, the secondary replica will "eventually" give you the data you wrote.

Comment: I'm fairly new to MongoDB, but I'm going to guess it's a single one... Also, I don't think it's entering that statement, the users it's updating all seem to be in the database and have been updated before (they can't enter the arena to start with if they're new or dataReturned is "err"). I'll add a console log to this statement to ensure though